# Add href inside material tooltip

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material, tooltip

I have material info icon which has a tooltip. How to add link in a tooltip?

```
<i matTooltip='Make Changes<a href="https://myweb.com">here</>' matTooltipClass="tooltipFont" matTooltipPosition="above" class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" style="float:right;margin-right: 8%"></i>
```

So the tooltip looks like below

Make Changes [here](https://myweb.com)

Answer (score 3):

HTML content is not supported in mat tooltip.
Reference: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/5440#issuecomment-313740211

Answer (score 1):

As @Pandiyan Cool mentioned HTML is not supported in mat-tooltip. Instead you can use SAT Popover: https://ncstate-sat.github.io/popover/
You can easily put HTML content in it and design as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [sat-popover](https://github.com/ncstate-sat/popover) in Angular.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ncstate-sat-popover-examples-v2nh5v